# Passing important data to batch operation

Tags: batch-operations

I can't seem to pass any info to the 'finished' function of this batch operation.  Everything works in terms of data getting saved correctly but I get the following error message due to the 'finished' function looking for things that don't exist.

> Notice: Undefined index: created in my_csv_import_finished()
> (line 280 of
> /var/www/html/mysite.com/sites/all/modules/custom/my_csv/my_csv.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: updated in my_csv_import_finished()
> (line 281 of
> /var/www/html/mysite.com/sites/all/modules/custom/my_csv/my_csv.module).

And that's because there is no $success, $results, or $operations being passed to my_csv_import_finished

The $context variable is indeed being passed to the $operations function but from what I can tell, there is nothing there that would give me access to any sort of 'created' and/or 'updated' key of this $contexts array.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function my_csv_import_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // Check to make sure that the file was uploaded to the server properly
  $uri = db_query("SELECT uri FROM {file_managed} WHERE fid =:fid", array(
                   ':fid' => $form_state['input']['import']['fid'],
                  ))->fetchField();
 if(!empty($uri)) {
   if(file_exists(drupal_realpath($uri))) { 
     // Open the csv
     $handle = fopen(drupal_realpath($uri), "r");
     $fp = file($uri);
     $total_rows = count($fp);


     // this is somewhat of a hack to skip the first line (headers)
     fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"');
     
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {
     $operations[] = array('my_csv_import_batch_processing', array($data), 
    );
  }

    $batch = array(
      'title' => t('Importing CSV...'),
      'operations' => $operations, array($data),  
      'finished' => 'my_csv_import_finished', 
      'error_message' => t('The installation has encountered an error.'),
      'progress_message' => t('Processed @current of @total rows.'),
    );
    batch_set($batch);

    fclose($handle);    
  }
 }

function my_csv_import_batch_processing($data, &$context) {
  watchdog('$context', print_r($context,TRUE));

  .....
}
```

What am I supposed to use here?

$context looks like this:

```
[0] => Array (
            [sandbox] => Array (
                )
            [results] => Array (
                )
            [finished] => 1
            [message] => ''
        )
```

If I've indeed successfully updated a node, where is this info?  And how do I get/find it?

Is it something to do with the structure of what's being passed to the operations function?

Comment: Frank, you can add an answer to your own questions. That is preferred over editing the answer into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Soon after posting this I figured out that one can simply pass things into the $context['results'] array like so:

```
$context['results'][].
```